# show different column value from single column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to show the single column value to gridview different column..

For example : 
             My column value is "Casual Leave:12-Medical Leave :13-Annual Leave :03" ..
I want to split the above string value and show the above values in a grid colulmn like this...

```
 Employee Id   Employee Name  Casual Leave     Medical Leave    Annual Leave

 00624323      James          12               13               03
 00624324      Fernando       12               14               05
```

Note: Employee Id and Employee Name are different column

My partial code is here :

```
DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_getallempleaveTableAdapter TA = new    DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_getallempleaveTableAdapter();
DataSet5.sp_getallempleaveDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
        if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataView datavw = new DataView();
            datavw = DS.DefaultView;
            datavw.RowFilter = "fldempid='" + txtempid.Text + "' and fldempname='" + txtempname.Text + "'";
            if (datavw.Count > 0)
            {
                string leavehistory = Convert.ToString(datavw[0]["fldleavehistory"]);
                string[] textarray = leavehistory.Split('-');
                foreach (string samtext in textarray)
                {
                    if (samtext.StartsWith(leavehistory))// I want to check the string with array value
                    {
                        string newtext = samtext.Split(':')[1];
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

what i do? please help me to solve this

Comment: Since you have the split string logic why not push them into the correct cells in the `row databound` event of the grid ?

Answer (score 0):

Having such a compound column in your database is never a good idea. Why don't you just split the column into 3 columns (CasualLeave, MedicalLeave and AnnualLeave), each containing a number?

Answer (score 0):

With the leavehistory and newtext either you can make a datatable and bind it  to gridview or u can change your sp to directly return splitted result.

since u have coded so much in client side its now better to make a new datatable and feed rows into it and add this datatable to the gridsource

Edit :-

Example :-

```
DataTable newdatatable = new DataTable("New");
newdatatable.Columns.Add("Employee Id");
newdatatable.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
newdatatable.Columns.Add("Casual Leave");
newdatatable.Columns.Add("Medical Leave");    
newdatatable.Columns.Add("Annual Leave");
newdatatable.AcceptChanges();
DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_getallempleaveTableAdapter TA = new    DataSet5TableAdapters.sp_getallempleaveTableAdapter();    
DataSet5.sp_getallempleaveDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
if (DS.Rows.Count > 0)
{
      DataView datavw = new DataView();
      datavw = DS.DefaultView;
      datavw.RowFilter = "fldempid='" + txtempid.Text + "' and fldempname='" + txtempname.Text + "'";
      if (datavw.Count > 0)
      {
          string leavehistory = Convert.ToString(datavw[0]["fldleavehistory"]);
            string[] textarray = leavehistory.Split('-');DataRow drow = newdatatable.NewRow();
                    drow[0]=txtempid.Text;
                    drow[1]=txtempname.Text;
            foreach (string samtext in textarray)
            {
                if (samtext.StartsWith(leavehistory))// I want to check the string with array value
                {                        
                    drow[samtext.Split(':')[0]]=samtext.Split(':')[1];
                }
            }
            newdatatable.Rows.Add(drow);
            newdatatable.AcceptChanges();
        }
}
gridview1.DataSource=newdatatable;
```

Comment: Please Check the Edit .P.S. I dont have dev environment right now. But with minor changes I guess the code should work. Sorry If I did any blunders.